# Express 4 session TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am learning nodejs with Express 4 to develop a web app and following some blogs, this error is shown when trying to launch the project:

```
[nodetest1]# npm start

nodetest1@0.0.0 start /root/node_proyects/nodetest1
node ./bin/www

/root/node_proyects/nodetest1/app.js:64
app.use(session({secret: 'blablabla'}));
        ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/node_proyects/nodetest1/app.js:64:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/node_proyects/nodetest1/bin/www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

This is head of app.js file:

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride()); //**
app.use(passport.initialize()); //**
app.use(passport.session()); //**
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({secret: 'blablabla'}));
```

and package.json file where modules are loaded in the project:

```
[nodetest1]# cat package.json
{
  "name": "nodetest1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-method-override": "*",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "^4.1.1",
    "monk": "~1.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "session": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Is there any problem with the version of session/Express 4 or the code?

I have googled around and did not find any clues on how to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to declare `var session = require('express-session');` but you have `express-session` and something else called `session` in your `package.json` file, which you might be confusing for the former.

Comment: express-session is the old module for expression 3.x and above. I deleted it from the package.json and just kept session module, but the same error is arisen: 
`/root/node_proyects/nodetest1/app.js:64 app.use(session({secret: 'blablabla'})); ^ TypeError: object is not a function at Object.<anonymous> (/root/node_proyects/nodetest1/app.js:64:9)`

Comment: Incorrect. express-session, body-parser, cookie-parser, et al became their own modules for express 4.x, which are still being maintained by the expressjs team. Your code `app.use(session({secret: 'blablabla'}));` is valid, but it only works for express-session. Remove `session` from your package.json, put `express-session` back in, `var session = require('express-session');` back at the top of your app.js file and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes xDHILEx, you are right. I missunderstood what I read from a blog. Here is the correct info:
[MIgrating to Express 4](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html)

Answer (score 2):

I came here because on the site https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/session#use-with-express-default I was instructed to `import * as session from 'express-session';` to use:

```
app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'my-secret',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    }),
  );
```

But in my case I got the error "TypeError: session is not a function (Type 'typeof session' has no call signatures.)".

Here I have to import the default export from express-session instead of importing the namespace (which is an object with all named exports). So all I had to do was `import session from 'express-session';`